# HaxeFlixel, loadGraphic() for a Bitmap

Tags: bitmap, haxe, haxeflixel

I have problems triying to set a `Bitmap` in the method `loadGraphic()` of the SpriteSheet.

```haxe
var bd:BitmapData = Assets.getBitmapData("images/MenuDoorTopV1.0_640x260.png");
var b:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bd);

_CompuertaTop = new FlxSprite(-1000, -1000);
_CompuertaTop.loadGraphic(b, false, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the actual `BitmapData` instance to `loadGraphic()`.

Also, there's no need to use `Assets.getBitmapData()` in this case, `loadGraphic()` does that call for you if you pass the String path:

`_CompuertaTop.loadGraphic("images/MenuDoorTopV1.0_640x260.png", false, 0, 0);`

Comment: If I use loadGraphic(), I can't embed that asset in the game
How can I embed Images using loadGraphic() ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "can't embed"?

Comment: I'm trying to hide all the assets of my game (embed the assets)

Comment: On native targets I presume? Typically you'd accomplish this either by setting the `embed="true"` when including the assets in the project file, or by using `@:bitmap`, but neither of that has anything to do with `loadGraphic()`.